# Using ConcurrentDictionary in a PCL from a UWP app

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library, uwp, concurrentdictionary

I recently had a problem and would like some explanation of why :

In a Portable Class Library (PCL) using **Profile5** (.Net 4, Windows 8) I have this code :

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

public class Foo
{
    public static void Bar(ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> dict)
    {
        dict.AddOrUpdate("true", true, (k, v) => true);
    }

    public static void Baz()
    {
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>();
    }
}
```

Using `Bar` in a Windows 10 UWP application like this :

```
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>();
Foo.Bar(dict);
```

It compile but crash with :

> Method not found: 'Void Foo.Bar(System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2)'.

A call to Baz fails differently with :

> Attempt by method 'Foo.Baz()' to access method 'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2..ctor()' failed.

So what it seem is that the `TypeForwardedTo` magic isn't working in this case, or is missing. The compiler understand that it should be the same types (Even if present in different assemblies) but the runtime doesn't.

At runtime using reflection I can see that there is really 2 `ConcurrentDictionary` types :

- `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary'2[[TKey, TValue]], System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` when I use `typeof(ConcurrentDictionary<,>)`
- And `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary'2[[TKey, TValue]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e` when I use reflection on `Bar` parameter.

Changing the PCL to a profile that uses 4.5 instead of 4.0 (Where the new `System.*` libraries are referenced) make everything work correctly.

What I don't get is why isn't there some form of mapping in place like there is in most other cases ? Is something stopping microsoft from creating it ?

(It's pretty confusing to have "Portable" libraries be non portable. Especially when they can be half portable and only crash when some part of the code is reached at runtime)

***Note***: I'm not searching for workaround, i'll do without `ConcurrentDictionary`, (or without UWP) for this project, i'm more searching for an explanation of why a so big usability problem between UWP and PCL is present.

Comment: I had to try it to believe it. What a mess... I guess that explains why up-to-date nuget packages such as json.net provide different binaries for PCL 4.0 and PCL 4.5